# Spring is converting String values to false for @queryparam Boolean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations

I have this as queryparam in my requestmapping:
@QueryParam("isBenchmark") boolean isBenchmark

Now if am passing any String value also it is defaulting it to false. How can I avoid this and throw error if it is anything other than true/false.
Is there any annotations with which I can throw such validations

Comment: Can't reproduce. Using `jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam` from jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.0.0.jar, Spring Boot 2.7.5 and Spring 5.3.23, the boolean query parameter is true when the caller passes "true", "yes", "on" or "1", and false for "false", "no", "off" or "0" (case-insensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue.

It is converted to boolean using the `new Boolean(isBenchmark)` So when `isBenchmark` is true it converts to true, in all other cases it converts to false.

Unfortunately you have to handle it by your self

```
 public void YourMethod(@QueryParam("isBenchmark") String isBenchmark) {
 boolean val
 if (isBenchmark != null && isBenchmark.equals("true")){
   val = true;
 } else if (isBenchmark != null && isBenchmark.equals("false")) {
   val = false;
 } else {
   Throw Exception or return a bad request
  }
}
```